# screen immediately closing after opening payment screen of paytm in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, payment, paytm

I am trying to integrate paytm in my react native app. but when I tap on pay button paytm screen is opening but closing immediately . please help here is code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import AllInOneSDKManager from "paytm_allinone_react-native";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const orderDetails = {
  orderId: "TESTORDER_1",
  mid: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  tranxToken: "0b0b2fb76846429ea5c146a5cd2c84a21626407545344",
  amount: "1.00",
  callbackUrl:
    "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=TESTORDER_1",
  isStaging: true,
  appInvokeRestricted: false,
};

export default class payment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      order_id: "",
      checksum: "",
    };
  }

  handleTransaction = () => {
    AllInOneSDKManager.startTransaction(
      orderDetails.orderId,
      orderDetails.mid,
      orderDetails.tranxToken,
      orderDetails.amount,
      orderDetails.callbackUrl,
      orderDetails.isStaging,
      orderDetails.appInvokeRestricted
    )
      .then((result) => {})
      .catch((err) => {});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ alignSelf: "center", flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.handleTransaction}
        >
          <Text >
            PAY 20/-
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

please ignore it I am trying to integrate paytm in my react native app. but when I tap on pay button paytm screen is opening but closing immediately . please help here is codeI am trying to integrate paytm in my react native app. but when I tap on pay button paytm screen is opening but closing immediately . please help here is codeI am trying to integrate paytm in my react native app. but when I tap on pay button paytm screen is opening but closing immediately . please help here is codeI am trying to integrate paytm in my react native app. but when I tap on pay button paytm screen is opening but closing immediately . please help here is code

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have Paytm Staging app installed in your device. You can get the link from Paytm developer portal